# Unable to build External library dependencies

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dependencies

I am trying to build ClamAV source code using visual studio 2017 the guide on ClamAV git says:

External library dependencies:

> ClamAV relies on a handful of 3rd party
> libraries.  In previous versions of ClamAV, most of these were
> copy-pasted into the win32/3rdparty directory, with the exception
> being OpenSSL.
>
> In ClamAV 0.102, all of these libraries are now
> external to ClamAV and must be compiled ahead of time as DLLs (or for
> zlib, a static lib) and placed in the %CLAM_DEPENDENCIES% (typically
> C:\clam_dependencies) directory so the ClamAV Visual Studio project
> files can find them.

To build each of these libraries, we recommend using Mussels. Mussels is an open-source application dependency build tool that can build the correct version of each dependency using the build tools intended by the original library authors."

https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-devel/blob/dev/0.102/win32/README.md

But Mussels is not available anywhere. any other solution will be helpful also I tried adding the dependencies manually but the errors are still there.

[Build Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmZqJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, the Mussels tool was not yet open-sourced.  The Mussels project has since been made public.

See: https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/Mussels

To build the ClamAV dependencies with Mussels on Windows, you will need the following tools:

Mussels dependencies:

- Python 3.6+
- Git (added to your PATH environment variable)

Build tools needed to build ClamAV's dependencies:

- Visual Studio 2017  (2019 may work, not sure)
- CMake
- ActivePerl (required for openssl)
- NASM (required for openssl)

Install Mussels:

```
pip install --user mussels
```

**Important**: Run the following in cmd.exe or powershell in an empty directory or in a small directory tree.  Mussels will recursively index your current working directory looking for recipes.  This will take a really long time if you run these commands from a large directory tree like your home directory.

```
mkdir clam_dependencies
cd clam_dependencies
```

Update the Mussels cookbooks:

```
mussels update
msl up        # (shorthand)
```

*Tip*: If the `mussels` or `msl` commands don't work, you may not have the Python 3 scripts directory in your %PATH%.  If you don't care to add it to your %PATH%, you can still execute Mussels with `python -m mussels` instead of using `msl`.  Eg:

```
python -m mussels up
```

Enable trust for ClamAV's recipe cookbook so you can build the ClamAV recipes:

```
msl cookbook trust clamav -y
```

List available build recipes:

```
msl list
msl list -V    # (verbose)
```

**Build ClamAV with Mussels for the current archicture**

Perform a dry-run of the build.  This will show you the dependency chain and may complain if you're missing any of the required tools:

```
msl build clamav -v 0.102 --dry-run
```

Build ClamAV.  The optional `--install <directory>` option is used to install to `.\clamav` rather than the default `%HOME%\.mussels\install\<target>\clamav`:

```
msl build clamav -v 0.102 --install clamav
```

**Or, build just the dependencies (for 64-bit and then 32-bit target architectures)**

Build the ClamAV dependencies.  The optional `--install <directory>` option is used to install them to `.\x64` and `.\x86` rather than the default `%HOME%\.mussels\install\<target>`:

```
msl build clamav_deps -v 0.102 --target x64 --install x64
msl build clamav_deps -v 0.102 --target x86 --install x86
```

Rename the `x86` directory to `Win32`, so it matches the name expected by ClamAV's Visual Studio project file.

```
mv .\x86 .\Win32
```

Create an environment variable named `CLAM_DEPENDENCIES` and set the value to the full path of the `clam_dependencies` directory. Eg:

```
setx CLAM_DEPENDENCIES C:\Users\gary\clam_dependencies
```

At this point, you should be ready to build ClamAV on Windows using the Visual Studio project file.

I hope that helps!  Please submit an issue on GitHub if you believe you've encountered a bug with Mussels https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/Mussels/issues or to https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-mussels-cookbook/issues if you think you've found an issue with the ClamAV build recipes.

There is a Mussels Discord server listed in the README if you want to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you @micah build completed successfully .